# Loop not ending, iOS, Swift

Tags: arrays, loops

I have a loop running that adds to an array each pass but I also check a number each pass and add 1 to it.

For some reason it seems to not stop when the number reaches the same as pCodes.count(which at this moment = 2)

Because it doesn't stop at 1 running through 0 and 1 it crashes when it hits 2 because there is only 2 items in the array.

Below is my code.

```
self.places = self.pCodes
                            for eachAddress in self.places {

                                let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
                                geocoder.geocodeAddressString(eachAddress) {
                                    placemarks, error in
                                    let placemark = placemarks?.first
                                    let lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
                                    let lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude
                                    let locationTitle = self.cNames[self.lt]
                                    let latLon = ["title": locationTitle, "latitude":lat!, "longitude": lon!] as [String : Any]

                                    self.posts.append(latLon)
                                    print("Tony: \(self.posts)")
                                    print("Tony: LTnum is: \(self.lt)")

                                        print("Tony: count is \(self.pCodes.count)")
                                    if self.lt < self.pCodes.count {
                                    self.lt += 1
                                    print("Tony: LTnum is: \(self.lt)")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                            self.showSightingsOnMap()
```

with the crash

> Tony: [["latitude": 50.800523599999998, "longitude": -1.0723248000000001, "title": "ASDFASD"]]
>   Tony: LTnum is: 0
>   Tony: count is 2
>   Tony: LTnum is: 1
>   Tony: [["latitude": 50.800523599999998, "longitude": -1.0723248000000001, "title": "ASDFASD"], ["latitude": 50.802415099999997, "longitude": -1.0726989, "title": "QWERQWE"]]
>   Tony: LTnum is: 1
>   Tony: count is 2
>   Tony: LTnum is: 2
>   app was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
>   (lldb)

Comment: That doesn't look like a crash. It looks like the debugger stopped at a breakpoint. It's telling you that you can step through the code (though it's warning that it might not work as expected.)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone needing the same result this is how I achieved it. It was looping and ended lt as 2 with only 2 elements in the array  it lt had gone from 0.1.2 looking for 3 elements where there was only 2. So i did a check to see if it was the same as pCode array -1 and if it was it deducted 1 from lt so that it never hit 2(3 elements) and this worked nice.

self.places = self.pCodes

```
                            for eachAddress in self.places {
                                let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
                                geocoder.geocodeAddressString(eachAddress) {
                                    placemarks, error in
                                    let placemark = placemarks?.first
                                    let lat = placemark?.location?.coordinate.latitude
                                    let lon = placemark?.location?.coordinate.longitude
                                    let locationTitle = self.cNames[self.lt]
                                    let latLon = ["title": locationTitle, "latitude":lat!, "longitude": lon!] as [String : Any]

                                    self.posts.append(latLon)

                                    if self.lt < (self.pCodes.count - 1) {
                                    self.lt += 1

                                    }else {
                                        self.lt = (self.pCodes.count - 1)
                            }
                                        self.showSightingsOnMap()
                        }
                    }
```